# Does this code produce date groupings that overlap, or are they mutually exclusive?

Tags: r, date

```
proact2$RealDate <- as.Date(proact2$DATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
dategp <- seq(min(proact2$RealDate), max(proact2$RealDate) + 3, by = 3)
proact2$Period1 <- cut(proact2$RealDate, dategp,
                   labels = paste(dategp[-length(dategp)], dategp[-1], sep = " - "))
```

The above code takes this date range in the data below

```
dat
#   OBJECTID     District        Zone year_value FROM_DATE SUM_Crime   RealDate                 Period1
# 1        1 Northwestern Not in Zone       2019  2/6/2019         4 2019-02-06 2019-02-06 - 2019-02-09
# 2        2 Northwestern     Zone 30       2019  2/7/2019         6 2019-02-07 2019-02-06 - 2019-02-09
# 3        3 Northwestern     Zone 40       2019  2/8/2019         5 2019-02-08 2019-02-06 - 2019-02-09
# 4        4 Northwestern     Zone 30       2019  2/9/2019         2 2019-02-09 2019-02-09 - 2019-02-12
# 5        5 Northwestern Not in Zone       2019 2/10/2019         4 2019-02-10 2019-02-09 - 2019-02-12
# 6        6 Northwestern     Zone 40       2019 2/11/2019         4 2019-02-11 2019-02-09 - 2019-02-12
# 7        7 Northwestern     Zone 30       2019 2/12/2019         0 2019-02-12 2019-02-12
```

However I notice that the RealDate, if it falls on the 9th for example (row# 4), goes into the next Period1 bucket, the one ending on 2-12. How can I adjust this procedure so that instead of the first date in the Period1 variable being where RealDate is placed, it is based upon the last date in Period1. So Row4 for example, instead of going into 2/9 to 2/12 Period1, it would go into 2/6-2/9 Period1 group.

Also, how would I change how Period1 is formatted so that the groups do not share the same date. I would like it so that the 2/9 to 2/12 Period1 group is called 2/10 to 2/13 and so on (to reflect the process I also want to do here).

Thank you.